# Change Navigation Bar title color and back button title color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I want to change the `UINavigationBar` `titleColor`.

I also want to change the `textColor` of the `UINavigationBar` `backButton`.

I am using iPhone Os sdk 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One part of this question [has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color).

Then, to change the back button title color, I would suggest creating a custom button with a label:

```
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourViewWithColoredText];
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem; // assign it as the left button
```

`yourViewWithColoredText` should be a custom view containing your colored text.
Then depending on what you want, you could make it look like a standard back button.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

Using this you can change the color of all of the navigation buttons:

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Replace redColor with the following to adjust the color of the buttons:

```
colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:144/255.0 blue:200/255.0 alpha:1.0// pick your color using this
```

Be sure to put this in the view controller that pushes.  Not the view controller where you want to see this back button color.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the titleView, defined in UINavigationBar.h as:

```
 @property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *titleView;
// Custom view to use in lieu of a title. May be sized horizontally. Only used when item is topmost on the stack.
```

Pop your own UILabel in there with whatever color you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[button setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `title` on `UINavigationBar` on iOS 5 & 6

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor]];
```

On iOS 7

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};
```

---

---

Set the `textColor` on all `UIBarButtonItem`

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                    [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```