# Change title's color of navigation Controller ! [iPhone SDK]

Tags: iphone

i want change title's color of navigation controller but i dont know why doesn't work !

```
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Navigation Bar Title text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i figured out my problem :

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 44);
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];

    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
    label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"YOUR TEXT", @"");
```

now how can add a logo on my navigation bar  ? :D

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the UILabel your not giving it a size so its ending up with a frame of 0x0 - by adding `[label sizeToFit];` after you've added the text you'll get what you want.

Or you can set the size of the label when you create it with `initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the color of the whole navigation bar or just the UILabel in the middle of it? Assuming you want to recolor the whole bar, you can do it in Interface Builder by setting the tint color, or you can use `navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(...)`