# how to change front color of navigation bar title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I am using navigation controller in my application and want to change title color of navigationBar.

I am doing so using below code

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor grayColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil];
    [self.navController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:dic];
```

One more thing I am using ARC xcode 4.2 and this code is placed on appdelegate only

It is working fine in ios 4+
but not working on below versions.

Please help me how to do this from single code on appdelegate

Comment: The code you post is for iOS 5, if you want it to work on iSO 4 you won't be able to do it in a single line of code in the appdelegate.

Comment: this question is already answered in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can recreate the titleView like that in your viewcontroller:

```
UILabel * titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
titleView.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
titleView.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
titleView.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Your color here
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
[titleView sizeToFit];
[titleView release];
```

the other parameters are those wich are used in the native titleView.

**

### Please look at Max Strater's answer below to have a more recent solution.

**

Answer (score 17):

I was just looking for the same thing and found Alex R. R.'s easy solution using iOS 5:

```
NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                            [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                            [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(-1, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];
```

Reference:
[iPhone Navigation Bar Title text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color)

Answer (score 7):

After iOS 5,  just do this :

```
    nav1.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
```

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 7, just use:

```
self.navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

Change `[UIColor whiteColor]` with whatever text color you want.

Answer (score 2):

in iOS 7 this is how you can change the color of Navbar title/text:

```
UIColor *red = [UIColor colorWithRed:254.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

NSMutableDictionary *navBarTextAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];

[navBarTextAttributes setObject:red forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName ];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarTextAttributes;
```