# Change of font and text color in NavBar

Tags: iphone, xcode, fonts, colors, navbar

Is it possible to change the default text font and color in NavBar?

It seems to be Helvetica something by default.

I use

```
self.title = @"Countries";
```

to set the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `UILabel` and add that as subview to `titleView` of the navigation bar.

For more info, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color) SO question.

Edit: FYI, new in iOS5.0 you can easily customize the navigation bar with

[-[UINavigationbar titleTextAttributes]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/titleTextAttributes)