# iOS UINavigationBar Title Text Color (iOS 4)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uinavigationbar, textcolor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Navigation Bar Title text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color)

I am trying to change the text color of the navigation title bars in my application. I have managed to do this in iOS 5 using the new appearance API's, but having looked at various threads on how to do so on iOS 4 I am still lost.

I would like to be able to set the text color for the UINavigationBar on all of my View Controllers to a certain color, for iOS 5 I used the appearance method in my AppDelegate, but completely unsure how to do this for iOS 4.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Try Erik B's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color You have to add it to each view controller though.

Answer (score 1):

Prior iOS 5.0 I think you have to use a custom view like a UILabel customized like you want and set it to the navigation bar with:

```
 [self.navigationItem setTitleView: myLabel];
```

You can see the doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView).

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Aguin said, and change the color of your label.

Hint: Put in your header:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Then change the color of your label with:

```
[self.navigationItem setTitleView: myLabel];
UIColor* titleColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff6600); //An orange color for example
myLabel.textColor = titleColor;
```