# Xcode UINavigationBar Text font and color

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, colors, uinavigationbar

I want to change the *color* and *font* of my **UINavigationBar title**. How can i do that either with code or with interface builder ? It might be an easy one but i'm new to xcode. Thanks for helping.

Comment: check this out-- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color

Answer (score 0):

For the coding part, what you can do is initiate the title view with a label.

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 40)];
[myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12]];
[myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myLabel setText:@"My text here"];
[**your navigation bar**.topItem setTitleView:myLabel];
```