# No response from colorWithRed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicolor

I am developing an application where I want to change font color of Navigation bar title and text label of Table cell.

I am using following code snip to change color

```
[mantraLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:89 green:45 blue:15 alpha:1]];
```

and configuring table cell as follow,

```
NSString *cellValue = [mantra objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    mantraLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    mantraLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,4,200,44)];
    mantraLabel.text=cellValue;
    [mantraLabel setBaselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters];
    [mantraLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marathi-Vakra" size:21.0]];
    [cell addSubview:mantraLabel];
    [mantraLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:89 green:45 blue:15 alpha:1]];
```

But the Issue I am facing is that no color change is there with above statement and also one of my cell background is appearing in white color.

Comment: I think this will solve your problem [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/599405/2407907)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
[cell addSubview:mantraLabel];
    [mantraLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:89 green:45 blue:15 alpha:1]];
```

With

```
[mantraLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0f green:45/255.0f blue:15/255.0f alpha:1]];
[cell addSubview:mantraLabel];
```

Add your Label after set color

Comment: Is this helpful to you??

Answer (score 3):

Correct your this line

```
[mantraLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:89 green:45 blue:15 alpha:1]];
```

with

```
[mantraLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0 green:45/255.0 blue:15/255.0 alpha:1]];
```

Your color comes within the the range of **0.0 to 1.0**. And we hardly use this way to specify colors. So in order to specify color within this range we need to **divide it using 255.0**

Comment: thanks it worked for me.... can u please tell me what is issue with the line that I have used

Comment: @Bhagyashreemahajan URW :)

Comment: @Bhagyashreemahajan see my post for an explanation of why it didn't work.

Comment: @Bhagyashreemahajan if anything solve your issue accept the answer so that others know the correct answer for the question

Comment: @Bhagyashreemahajan  The function colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha is 1 based. so we are using  (89/255) .

Comment: Review this - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:

Answer (score 0):

The function `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha` is 1 based.

i.e. 89 = 0.349 ... (89/255)

You should use...

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.349 green:0.176 blue:0.058 alpha:1.0];
```