# address book colors changed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The navigation bar in my app has white text and when the user opens the address book it should be the normal color (blue text). I tried changing the text color before pushing the address book view but the titles (groups, cancel) are still white. How can I solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

edit: The title in the middle (all contacts) is like default black.
I already tried

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

before pushing the address book view, but that didn't work.

I also tried

```
[picker.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName]];
picker.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
picker.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
```

but these didn't work neither.

Fixed the problem with

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:nil];
```

Comment: Maybe this post could be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color

Comment: They want to change the default color in that post, but I just want the default one.

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationController *nac = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addBookViewController]autorelease];
NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                [UIColor whiteColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,nil];

nac.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;
[nac.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: I don't have a AddressbookViewController. I push the view with
`ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
 picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: The ABPeoplePickerNavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController. Try picker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;
[picker.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];