# Need change title navbar color

Tags: ios, objective-c

Need change navigationbar title color. 
Something like that:

```
self.navigationItem.title.color = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9454828/155187

Comment: You need to say what version of iOS you are targeting. There are two different ways to do this: for versions before iOS 7 or for iOS 7 and later.

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];

    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];

    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
// In dictionary you can set your own color

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

}
```

for more...

go to http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

you can give any stylish you want to tittle of navigation bar by just doing

```
UILabel *lblNavTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    lblNavTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblNavTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lblNavTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//this what you want
    lblNavTitle.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Volunteers", @"");
    [lblNavTitle sizeToFit];
     self.navigationItem.titleView = lblNavTitle;
```