# Navigation Bar bar appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

how do you change you navbar placeholder text color? also is there a light blue color for these messages?

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Navigation Bar Title text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this will work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 [super viewDidLoad];

//I am using UIColor BlueColor for an example but you can use whatever color you like

  self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor]};

//change the title here to whatever you like
   self.title = @"Home";

}
```