# How to change navigation bar title color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I tried to change title color like this, but it has no effect.

```
NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];
```

Maybe the problem that navigationbar style is black?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/621185/7250862

Comment: Have you checked my updated ans?

Comment: for ios 13 try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141195/6108739

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"The title";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITextAttributeTextColor` instead of `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` for the key, and it will work :)