# How to use UINavigationBarAppearance in iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13, uinavigationbarappearance

How do you use this new object to customize the navigation bar in iOS 13? I tried the following code in Objective-C but it's not working correctly. It only shows my title text attributes while a view controller is being pushed or popped on to the navigation stack.

```
UINavigationBarAppearance *appearance = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
appearance.titleTextAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
```

Here is the documentation for this object.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance?language=objc

Comment: Show how you apply this `appearance` variable to the nav bar.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. The documentation indicates just to make an object and set the properties.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It isn't enough to just create an instance of `UINavigationBarAppearance`. You have to actually set it on a `UINavigationBar` instance (or its appearance proxy).

```
// Setup the nav bar appearance
UINavigationBarAppearance *appearance = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
appearance.titleTextAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};

// Apply it to a specific nav bar
someNavBarInstance.standardAppearance = appearance;
// There are also the compactAppearance and scrollEdgeAppearance properties that can be set as needed.
```

If you want this same customization on all nav bars in the app, apply it to the `UINavigationBar.appearance` proxy.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.standardAppearance = appearance;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. How exactly do I do `UINavigationBar.appearance` in Objective-C?

Comment: See my updated answer. Naming your variable `appearance` makes that code a little confusing.

Comment: Ok, that seems to work! The only problem is it's not keeping my font size during animation for pushing and popping views. Is font size not supported anymore with appearance?

Comment: Maybe you have different settings for different nav bars. Note that if you want the whole app to use the same settings and you use the `UINavigationBar.appearance` proxy, make sure you set that in the app delegate before any code is run or any UI is created. The appearance proxy only applies to UI elements created after it is set.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what I'm doing but it's not working. Thanks for helping me get this far at least.

Comment: If you have `prefersLargeTitles` enabled, you'll also want to call `setLargeTitleTextAttributes`

Comment: I think this needs to be updated; `UINavigationBar.appearance` is failing to compile with an "ambiguous reference" error in iOS 13 + Swift 5

Comment: You saved my night dude.

Answer (score 2):

For me, even though I correctly set the appearance to the current UINavigationBar, it was still not working.

I found out that you need to call `navigationBar?.setNeedsLayout()`, if you set an updated appearance on a UINavigationBar that is already being displayed.

Answer (score -1):

in iOS13 you need to set the title color on the UINavigationBarAppearance object like here (Objective C version):

```
UINavigationBarAppearance *appearance = [[UINavigationBarAppearance alloc] init];
appearance.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
self.navigationController.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
```