# change the view controller title color in objective c

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

I want to change the view controller title color like that this one in black!

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this add this code in viewWillAppear function:-

pass the font name according to your font

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],
NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-regular" size:17]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Title color change for only one view controller:**

Use below code in `viewWillAppear`

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];
```

**Title color change for Entire Application:**

Use below code in `didFinishLaunching`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];
```